# Shifting array element by indexes

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have been trying to solve this program. I have a list of objects that look like this. Adding elements to an array based on their index position.

```
let A = {index: 0} 
let B = {index: 0} 
let C = { index: 2} 
let D = {index: 2} 
let E = { index: 1}
```

So if A get pushed inside the array it takes over an array index position 0. However, when B get pushed in the array, it will take over an index position. [B, A], and so on. It is sort of like first go in, first come out, except get shifted to the left. However, I want to do something like this. [B, A, C], I want to add D to index position of C. [B, A, D, C]. 
A is at index position 1. I want to insert E to index 1. [B, E, A, D, C]

Comment: where do you add the elements? please add the code as well.

Comment: You can probably use `Array.concat()`. Also please include the code you currently have when posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply splice the array for adding an object at the wanted index.

```js
var a = { index: 0, value: 'a' },
    b = { index: 0, value: 'b' },
    c = { index: 2, value: 'c' },
    d = { index: 2, value: 'd' },
    e = { index: 1, value: 'e' },
    array = [];

function add(array, object) {
    array.splice(object.index, 0, object);
}

add(array, a);
add(array, b);
add(array, c);
add(array, d);
add(array, e);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Oh right, removing `thanks in advance` from the question made it on-topic?! Thats interesting ...

Comment: No, but you complained about my answer, and now surprisingly you add an answer eventhough the question hasnt really changed...

Comment: right, after reading you answer and checking the wanted outcoume, i thought a concise answer would help.

Answer (score 3):

```
  function insert(array, el) {
     let pos = 0;
     while(array[pos].index < el.index) pos++;
     array.splice(pos, 0, el);
  }
```

Just do insertion sort and use `splice` to add the element.

Comment: @nina oh really? I think its really clear what the OP wants :)

Comment: Why do we need the while loop if we already know the position to insert at. Like doesn't OP mean to insert D at pos = 2 or did I misunderstand?

Comment: @hollyleaves actually that depends on how you interpret the question.

Comment: You're right, I see you actually tried to preserve the index order

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `splice` and check for the index attribute to insert at a specific position.

If the index attribute doesn't exist, push the object at the end.

```js
var decorate = (arr) => {
  arr.insertByIndex = (...objs) => {
    objs.forEach(obj => {
      if (!isNaN(obj.index)) arr.splice(obj.index, 0, obj);
      else arr.push(obj);
    });
  }
  
  return arr;
};

let A = {index: 0, desc: 'A'};
let B = {index: 0, desc: 'B'};
let C = {index: 2, desc: 'C'};
let D = {index: 2, desc: 'D'};
let E = {index: 1, desc: 'E'};

var array = decorate([]);
array.insertByIndex(D, A, C, B, E);

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```